# Move_uploaded_file() function shows errors

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to upload picture dynamically. The HTML code is:

```
<form method="post" action="" name="form1" id="form1" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <label for "file">Select Picture</label><br>
    <input type="file" name="file" id="file"><br>
    <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $_POST['pic'];?>" name="pic">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload" name="upload" id="upload"><br>
</form>
```

> After I write the following code it is showing me the error: " move_uploaded_file() [function.move-uploaded-file]: The second argument to copy() function cannot be a directory " and "Unable to move 'C:\xampp\tmp\phpB67C.tmp' to 'images/' ". The php code for this is:

```
if(isset($_POST['upload'])){
    $pic=$_POST['pic'];
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "images/".$pic); //."jpg"); 
}
```

Please tell me how to remove the error and be able to add and view the picture.

Comment: what does print_r($_POST); give you?

Comment: it gives me Array ( [pic] => [upload] => Upload )

Comment: Change isset($_POST['upload']) to  isset($_FILES['upload'])

Comment: Well, $_POST['pic'] is empty. Try to set $pic to any filename first. That should help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Change Like This

You can get file name with `$_FILES["file"]["name"]` variable. so if any file upload you have to get filename with this method and not get with `$_POST`

```
if(isset($_POST['upload']))
{
    $pic=$_FILES["file"]["name"];
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "images/".$pic); //."jpg"); 
}
```

Comment: For security reasons and to prevent collisions you should not use the original filename

Comment: ok but she wants to solve the error and it's actual code for this and if change filename it's easy to set `time()` function before filename

Comment: You are right. I just wanted to state that as it is useful to know

Comment: yes buddy you are also right but i include only necessary code for solve question and easy to understand

Answer (score 0):

I have make some change on your form

```
<form method="post" action="" name="form1" id="form1" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<label for "file">Select Picture</label><br>
<input type="file" name="file" id="file"><br>
<input type="hidden" value="<?php if(isset($name)){ echo $name; } ?>" name="pic">
<input type="submit" value="Upload" name="upload" id="upload"><br>
```

and php code is here, 
change the `MyUploadFolder` name to your folder path.

```
if(isset($_FILES['file']['name'])){
    $name= $_FILES['file']['name'];
    $tmp_name = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];

if(move_uploaded_file($tmp_name,"MyUploadFolder/".$name))
    {
    echo 'Uploaded';
    }
else{
    echo 'Please Choose a File';
    }
}
```